# floor function inequality $\frac{3c-3n-3}{2n+3} \geq \lfloor\frac{3c-3n}{2n+3}\rfloor$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I want to prove following statement:
$$\forall K\in \mathbb R  \exists c\in \mathbb N  c\geq K s.t.\forall n\in \left\{1,2,...,c-1\right\}: \frac{3c-3n-3}{2n+3} \geq \lfloor\frac{3c-3n}{2n+3}\rfloor$$
I dont know at all where to start!